# Get DataGrid Values

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

Guys I know this has been answered a million times, but how do I get the values from the row I select from my datagrid?  I have tried and tried but no luck at all.  The databinds to the datagrid fine, I use the selectedCellsChanged event but thats where I get stuck.

My code is as follows:-

```
XAML

    <Window x:Class="main.results"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="results" Height="500" Width="650">
        <Window.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="LocationsTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CLIENTNAME}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" | " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=POSTCODE}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" | " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CONTRACT NUMBER}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="125" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,12,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FF7907C1" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF7907C1" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedCellsChanged="dataGrid1_SelectedCellsChanged">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CLIENTNAME}" Header="CLIENT NAME" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CLIENTNAME}" Header="POSTCODE" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CONTRACT NUMBER}" Header="CONTRACT NUMBER" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Window>

C#

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data.Linq;
    using System.Data.SqlTypes;

    namespace main
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for results.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class results : Window
        {
            public results()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void dataGrid1_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
            {
               **//HOW DO I GET THE VALUES FROM SELECTED ROW?**
            }        
        }
    }
```

Comment: One question first: Why do you bind stuff AND use a `SelectedCellsChanged` event? What is the purpose of this event handler? There is probably a cleaner way to do it

Comment: Hi Damascus, I was using the dataGrid to give the user the opportunity to select a client, then using the contract number to populate a series of forms.  What would you suggest?

Comment: Your use of a `Binding` makes me assuming that you are working in MVVM, right? So paul's solution definitely works, sure, but would be a huge enforcement to the MVVM model! The clean way to do this is to bind the `SelectedItem`, and in your `ViewModel`, define the logic to create/refresh your forms. Keep in mind that manipulating your `DataGrid` in code-behind does not only ruin MVVM, but it also goes against the `DataGrid`'s architecture

Comment: Thanks Damascus, I will give this a bit more thought then.

Comment: If you need some code snippets feel free to ask =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `var dr = (DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItem;` to get the row

then `dr["columnName"];` to get values for the columns

Comment: ha ha it worked, honestly the amount of time I have been playing around with this!  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Not trying to be rude here, but while this sure works, it is definitely not the "clean" way to work with your `SelectedItem`. A simple `Binding` is highly advised